# Java 1.7. How to replace two characters side by side in a regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

I have the code:

```
String str = "1 */ * / 2";

str = str.replaceAll("\\*/", " ");

System.out.println(str);
```

He gives me the next result and it's correct:

> 1   * / 2

But I need to get the opposite result, and I do:

```
String str = "1 */ * / 2";

str = str.replaceAll("[^\\*/]", " ");

System.out.println(str);
```

and get:

> */ * /

But not:

> */

I need to get only these two characters together, excluding separately * and /

How can i do this?

Comment: Character classes, i.e. `[xxx]`, matches *single* characters only. `"\\*/"` and `"[\\*/]"` is not the same thing. The first matches `*` followed by `/`, the second matches one character being either `*` or `/`, which means that `"[^\\*/]"` matches one character being anything but `*` or `/`. A character class is not the answer here. --- The solution is the use of a `(?=xxx)` [zero-width positive look-ahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Answer (score 1):

`replaceAll(regex, replacement)` tries to search for pattern represented by `regex` and replace *that match* with content of `replacement`. If you don't want to replace it, but lets say only print it, instead of `String#replaceAll` use `Matcher#find` like

```
String str = "1 */ * / 2";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\*/");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while(m.find()){
    String match = m.group();
    //do something with match
    System.out.println(match);
}
```

Comment: `replaceAll("[^*/]+|\\*(?!/)|(?<!\\*)/", "")` would work too. See [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/73qjp6/1)

Comment: @Andreas While true, don't show it to OP, or he will end up using it instead of simple `Matcher#find`.